# Looking for an “easy to understand” description of the tfm file format

Tags: fonts

I try to understand TeX more deeply, and one part of it is the TFM (TeX font metric) file format. Is there an easy to understand yet complete description of it somewhere (perhaps free)?

I know I can look into the source code (which is what I am doing at the moment), but a nicely formatted article with images would help me understanding the file structure.

I am not looking for an "overall description". The description should be exact (which byte has which meaning), but it should help the reader (=me) with some illustrations and examples.

Comment: Actually I have written a TFM parser in Ruby loong time ago (https://github.com/pgundlach/rfil/blob/master/lib/tex/tfm.rb) - but still I'd like to know if there is some nice description of it somewhere.

Comment: `texdoc pltotf` and `texdoc tftopl`. And, of course [Fuchs' article on TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb02-1/tb02fuchstfm.pdf)

Comment: @egreg The two PDFs (`pltotf` and `tftopl`) are the ones I am using already - I didn't know about Fuchs' article, but it is not quite what I am looking for - I am looking for something similar to this PNG description (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Comment: David Fuchs' article is actually a description of the format, starting from the division into bytefields.

Comment: Appendix F of the MetaFont book: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfbook

Answer (score 7):

The only known sources about the TFM format are:

- `pltotf.web`
- `tftopl.web`
- [David Fuch's article on TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb02-1/tb02fuchstfm.pdf)
- Appendix F of the METAFONTbook

David Fuchs' article is very detailed and shows the meaning of all (groups of) bytes.

Comment: The book "TeX: the program" also includes information on TFM in the section that builds the TFM parser. It's in part 30: font metric data.