# Generating ligature from the encoding file

Tags: pdftex, ligatures, kerning

I have an encoding file with some tex encoding, I have to use the ligature and kerning instruction for the encoding to make a replacement two char into a single ligature. It looks like the following:

```
% LIGKERN parenleft parenright =: comma ;
```

All the three chars (`parenleft`, `parenright`, `comma`) are presented in the encoding. I try to replace the tex code (.tex):

```
()
```

But when I run the compilation procedure, and then try viewing the resulted (I use pdflatex) PDF.

```
Non-PDF special ignored!] (./hello1.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/enc/d
vips/hiptex/orthucs8.enc}<</usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/hiptex/irmucs.p
fb>>
```

I see that the encoding is picked up, but in PDF I see just the two parens separated as `()`, and not the comma `.`.

**Update:** I've found out that the ligatures can be setup in `.enc`, and applied to `.tfm`/`.vpl` files during generation them from `.afm`. So then i've added a line into `.enc` file:

```
% LIGKERN parenleft parenright =: comma ;
% LIGKERN quoteleft parenleft =: comma ;
```

And tried to make a `.vpl` from `.afm`, getting the following code in `.vpl`:

```
(LABEL O 50) (comment parenleft)                                     
(LIG O 51 O 54)
```

I'm seeing the only single ligature `parenleft parenright -> comma`, and there is no ligature `quoteleft parenleft -> comma`. That is strange. Why the `afm2tfm` refuses to generate all the ligatures?

Comment: Ligatures are not done in the .enc-file but in the tfm-file of the font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well, is there any editor text/or etc. to change tfm, and rules to change?

Comment: `.tfm`-files a binaries. You must convert them with `tftopl` to a text file and then back again with `pltotf`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is there any docs on how to edit the `pl`  file?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115099/looking-for-an-easy-to-understand-description-of-the-tfm-file-format.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanx, and one yet question, how to knwp why `167` is `\thinspace`, in context of microtype package

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've updated the question

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm about to update an old package using tfm ligatures from PS fonts and I'm interested in these sorts of questions.

Comment: @erreka my case turned out too complex, and all of my chars/ligatures are overflows the standard case for 256 chars...